# Best practice to represent members in an organisation

Tags: c#, oop, modeling

What would be the best practice to represent an organisation with members from an object oriented approach. Would it be better to store the members as a collection inside the organisation model like so:

```
public class Organisation
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Person> Members { get; set; }

    // the rest of the code
}
```

Or would it be better not to store them inside the Organisation, but rather make a reference in the Person class to the organisation(s), like this:

```
public class Organisation
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    // the rest of the code
}

public class Person
{
    public ICollection<Organisation> OrganisationMemberships { get; set; }

    // the rest of the code
}
```

Speaking of an approach which makes it necessary to deeply link both together, meaning the program would not only just present an organisation or a person, but pieces of informations from both.
Say, the number of section leaders in a company, which has it's name and total number of employees presented.
Also the model aims towards linked organisations as well, much like the structure of military units and/or subsidiaries.

What are the performance implications of both ways? Is one way clearly better than the other, or does it come down to personal preference?

Comment: To me it sounds like personal preference. But what will the relationship between the Person and Organization be? Will one person be allowed to join multiple organizations? If not then going the route of having a collection of Person as members in the Organization class will be best. A rule of thumb is to keep it simple: don't include too many references when you are not going to be using them.

Comment: Why would there be a best practice for something like this?

Answer (score 2):

As this is N:M relation it often comes down to implementation details... as in who actually needs the reference.

The main downside to having it in both sides is maintaining consistency - when you add/remove person to an organization, you also need to make sure that the opposite link gets add/removed as well.

Comment: agree! Maintaining consistency is a headache when application goes on a larger scale.